# Adding users to another blog

Tags: php, multisite, users

Good Morning...

I want to make a snippet that when creating a user in a blog add it automatically to another blog (this number 1 always) with the same roll that was created.

For this I am using this:

```
$ Blog_id = 1;
$ User_id = get_current_user_id ();
$ Role = 'publisher';
Add_action ('user_register', add_user_to_blog ($ blog_id, $ user_id, $ role));
```

.....And it does not work,

but if I do this....

```
$ Blog_id = 1;
$ User_id = 127; // 127 is a specific number of a user that already exists
$ Role = 'publisher';
Add_action ('user_register', add_user_to_blog ($ blog_id, $ user_id, $ role));
```

Then yes that works.

Can someone help me understand why the first (generic) solution does not work with:

```
$ User_id = get_current_user_id (); ?
```

Comment: Can you copy actual code into your question? `Add_action` should give a PHP fatal error for the upper case `A`, and there are spaces in strange places. `add_action` also expects a `callable` type value as the second parameter, e.g. a function name

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanna register any user to other blogs when a user is created. But this `get_current_user_id()` doesn't fire on user creation. You better have a look on `wp-includes/user.php` at **line 1401** the `wp_insert_user` function. WordPress default registering process uses this function to insert new users. And if you wanna create the user manually then you're also using this function. So if you use this `user_register` hook declared at **line 1707** at `wp-includes/user.php` inside `wp_insert_user` function then we can say that the hook will be executed all the time of creating new user and when the user is being created we'll assign this user to other blog like this-

```
$blog_id = 1;
//$user_id = 127; // You don't need to define user_id here.
$role = 'publisher';

add_action( 'user_register', function( $user_id ) use ( $blog_id, $role ) {
    add_user_to_blog ($blog_id, $user_id, $role);
}, 10, 1 );
```

Now come the problem of your code-

1. You can't do it like `Add_action ('user_register', add_user_to_blog ($ blog_id, $ user_id, $ role));`. The first mistake is it's `add_action`, small case `a`.
2. Second mistake is the second parameter doesn't take `add_user_to_blog ($ blog_id, $ user_id, $ role)` this kinda value. It takes a string which represents a callable function name.
3. You've defined the variable with capital letter and called with small letter.
4. You passed the variable to the callable function wrong way. Se my answer code for the fix.

Note that I used anonymous function and also used `use` keyword to pass value from outside.

Hope that helps.